# AS3: Could we convert .swf into .flv or play .swf into flash player

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-cs5

I'm searching for a program that can convert .swf into .flv and i can play that converted .flv into flash player. Is it possible in as3, Does anybody have any ideas?

I am not talking about any third party converter software.

Thanks,

Comment: You want a program that converts between formats but that isn't a converter? Hehe.

Comment: You can embed the fly into an swf directly in Flash, but a "real" conversion, generating vector data from the compressed video in an FLV, seems highly unlikely.

Comment: @weltraumpirat: how can i embed? could you provide any example?

Comment: In your Flash IDE, select File->Import->Import Video... ;)

Comment: that i know my question is not that how to import video into Flash IDE.

Comment: That's a bit like trying to convert a jpg to xls. What's the point?

Comment: There is absolutely no point in doing this. Might be, that the problem you're facing, requires a different approach.

Comment: No point in converting SWF to FLV?  Of course there is.  For example, I have thousands of AS2 facial animation SWFs that need to be playable in my upgraded AS3 system.  Opening the FLAs and modifying the publish settings > target player > target language > other settings > save in newest FLA format > re-encode / re-compile, etc. would be impractical.  SWF can be converted directly to FLV with this: http://www.swftovideo.net/swf-to-flv/   At the very least, the FLV files will have stripped out any obsolete AS2 code and will be smaller than the SWF which may use an older, less efficient codec.

Answer (score 1):

An swf file can directly be played by Flash Player. So I am assuming that you are trying to play your swf in a Video Player ( since video players can play the flv format if it is supported. ).

If you are going to be playing this swf file on the web, then with a high degree of probability you are going to be using one of JWPlayer or FlowPlayer. If this is the case, dont bother about conversion since they do directly play an swf file.

Answer (score 0):

".flv and convert it to an AS3 .swf file"

The way this is done 99% of the time is using the as3 api to load play the flv file itself, that is why projects like flow player for example.

See this page with a typical embed code. There are many more opensource flv players.
http://flowplayer.org/demos/plugins/flash/index.html

Is there some reason you want to embed the flv into a swf? There would be no difference for the user viewing the video.

Comment: Thanx a lot for your reply.  i had updated my question, please go through that. I have a .swf file which have some animation and i want to play that swf into .flv player.is it possibl with flash as3?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Download the flash plugin from adobe's website and play the flash file in a web browser (IE, chrome, firefox, etc.).
2. Download an SWF converter software, convert swf file to a different
   format (avi, mp4, etc.) and then play the file in your favorite
   video player.

For option (2), I'm using this [swf video converter](http://www.convertswf.com).

Answer (score -1):

The ".SWF to .FLV Converter" can batch convert SWF files to FLV files, among other formats.

Download here: http://www.swftovideo.net/swf-to-flv/

I loaded a bunch of old Flash 8 SWFs with audio and video (Sorenson Spark codec) into it and set the output to FLV, picked H.264 as my codec, etc., and it output the FLV files perfectly.  The only catch is that a watermark is included unless you enter a registration code.

This conversion process takes some time since it seems to play back the movie and capture frames.  The approach makes sense if there's actual vector animation, but there is probably a better way of extracting audio and video to FLV if the SWF is known to contain only an embedded video.

Comment: it doesn't open files at all